# How to get the Timestamp column value in android via cursor?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

How do I get the Timestamp value from database column via a cursor and store it in a Timestamp variable in android sdk?
I'm using the `java.sql.Timestamp` and the value in the sqlite database is of type TIMESTAMP.
I have created an class having all the fields as the database column names and wish to create a new object after reading a record from the database.

Comment: SQLite has no type `TIMESTAMP`. See [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to use the Cursor methods to get the value as a string and then use the Timestamp class's static valueOf method to convert it back to a proper Timestamp:

```
Timestamp.valueOf(cursor.getString(0))
```

I use this all over the place and it works like a charm.  For example, while iterating over the result set, you can set the Timestamp fields of your object.

```
obj.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
obj.setName(cursor.getName(1));
obj.setAddDate(Timestamp.valueOf(cursor.getString(2)));
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.